# Request is not going through mitm proxy when I am trying to hit it from Java Code

Tags: mitmproxy

I am trying trying to connect to a website(http) through my java code where I am setting target host as the mitm proxy, but on the proxy side I am getting this error

```
Invalid HTTP request form (expected: authority or absolute, got: relative)
xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx: HTTP protocol error in client request: Invalid HTTP request form (expected: authority or absolute, got: relative)
```

and in java response I am getting 400 Bad Request.

Below is the code I am trying to run:

```
        HttpHost target = new HttpHost("xx.x.x.x7", xxxx);

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://weevil.info/");
        post.addHeader("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");        
        CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();

           // send the post request
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(target, post);
        System.out.println(response);
```

Command used to run mitm:

```
mitmdump -p 8083 -s mitmProxy.py
```

Comment: Did you check this: https://github.com/mitmproxy/mitmproxy/issues/754 ? Running mimtproxy in transparent mode seems to work fine.